# Keep the whole prompt while clearing zsh terminal with oh-my-zsh

Tags: terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

So, I started using **zsh** and **oh-my-zsh** recently. I am using the *pure (refined)* theme and the prompt shows extra info above the prompt.

When I clear the Terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, the whole Terminal gets cleared but the line before the prompt that shows the current directory and git information also get cleared. When I type `clear` however, the line stays with the prompt while the Terminal gets cleared.

Is there a way to keep that line when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>? What does that shortcut point to and how can I change it? In my Terminal preferences (I'm on Manjaro Budgie), that key binding is absent in the shortcuts list.

Comment: This doesn't happen when I use the `pure` theme; both `clear` and `^L` draw the full 2-line prompt. You can see what `^L` is bound to with `bindkey | fgrep '^L'`. It defaults to `clear-screen`, which you can read about in `man zshzle`. But I suspect there's something else at fault; it should work without any hacks. I'd test a different terminal emulator (xterm, sakura, Konsole). Then I'd create a clean `.zshrc` with only `source /path/to/pure.zsh` and see if that works. Then gradually add more of your other config back in until you find the piece that is breaking it.

Comment: Tilix also behaves the same way. I'll try modifying my `.zshrc` file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely those extra lines are output by `precmd`, the hook that is run after each command and before the prompt. It is not called automatically upon `clear-screen` (bound on `^L`).

You could redefine `clear-screen` so it calls it though:

```
clear-screen() { echoti clear; precmd; zle redisplay; }
zle -N clear-screen
```